# Using ngModelController and $formatters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input. It should take a number and format it into currency for the view, while keeping the numeric value in the model. I have the text input itself and up/down buttons.

this ls what I have:

```
if (angular.isDefined(ngModel)) {
  ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
    var input;
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      return '';
    } else {
      value = format(value, formatStr);
      input = elm.children().find('input');
      return input.val(value);
    }
  });
}
```

It gets called, and I get the correct value from `format`.

I tried using `$render`, `$setViewModel`, and other things I could think of, to no avail. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your directive, and the HTML?  A plunker would help.

Comment: I assume you are doing this in a directive, and attaching the directive to the input? Your formatter should simply return the new value, so your else statement could be just "return format(value, formatStr);".

Comment: @aet that was the first thing I tried

Comment: @j.wittwer I'm getting some weird errors in jsfiddle that I don't get in my project :\

Comment: Even if there are errors in the fiddle, seeing it may make it more clear how you are trying to set up and use the directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
app.directive('format', function(format) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: {
      pre: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
        var formatStr;
        formatStr = attr.format;
        if (angular.isDefined(ngModel)) {
          ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            if (angular.isNumber(value)) {
              return value = format(value, formatStr);
            }
          });
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
            if (isNaN(value)) {
              value = ngModel.$modelValue;
            }
            return +value;
          });
          return elm.on('blur', function() {
            if (isNaN(elm.val())) {
              return elm.val(format(+ngModel.$modelValue, formatStr));
            } else {
              return elm.val(format(+elm.val(), formatStr));
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```